# Matplotlib different colour points depending on range of x

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got a scatter graph created from data I'm using, with plt.plot(), and wondered if there is an easy way to colour the points depending on where they are on the x axis? As in, if they lie between x0 and x1 make them green, x1 and x2 make them blue etc. Any help? Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You could use `plt.scatter`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("white")

x, y =  np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], [(1, .5), (.5, 1)], 200).T
c = np.where(x < 0, "#27ae60", "#2980b9")
plt.scatter(x, y, 30, c)
sns.despine()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get how to apply that to my case. I was wrong as well it's plt.semilogx() I'm using to plot the graph.

Comment: If you're committed to using `plt.plot` (which `semilogx` is using behind the scenes), you'll have to bin your data and plot each bin separately. With `scatter` you can pass an array of colors for each point. For your case, you can probably do `ax.set_xscale("log")` before plotting with `scatter`.

Comment: I'm still struggling with it. What is 30 in the scatter() ? And do I need "#27ae60", "#2980b9" those bits or can I get rid of them?

Comment: `30` is the size of the points and the two hex numbers are colors corresponding to the green and blue colors you see. Look at the docstring for `plt.scatter` for more info.

Comment: ah right yeah I see what it's doing now, thanks. How would I alter it to get one more range with a different colour? i.e. green/blue/red

Comment: For that you'll probably need to write a for loop and define a set of boolean masks.